# steepest descent with upper bound on steplength

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

I want to minimize an unconstrained optimization problem using steepest descent algorithm. Now, I want to fix the upper bound (say $\delta$) on the step length of line search i.e. we aren't allowed to move more than $\delta$ units along negative of gradient. Here $\delta$ is given directly by user and need not satisfy any Wolfe/Goldstein condition. Can we still guarantee convergence to some local optima with such an algorithm.

Comment: In this general form the answer is no. Assume for example you want to minimize f(x)=ax^2 Then the iteration is (1-2a \delta)x if a>\delta^(-1) this does not converge. However if you have a local minimizer and the eigenvalues of the Hessian at this point are bounded by 1/2 delta^(-1) you may have convergence.